# Angular 2 has no exported member 'trigger', 'state', 'animate', 'transition'

Tags: angular

```
import{ 
  Component, 
  OnInit, 
  trigger,
  state,
  style,
  animate,
  transition 
} from '@angular/core';
```

When I import OnInit, trigger,state,style,animate,transition from @angular/core as Angular2 ANIMATIONS tutorial do, but I got the below error when compiling.

cilent\app\components\home.component.ts(4,3): error TS2305: Module '"C:/Users/hcunwei/Library/Projects/codes/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'trigger'.
cilent\app\components\home.component.ts(5,3): error TS2305: Module '"C:/Users/hcunwei/Library/Projects/codes/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'state'.
cilent\app\components\home.component.ts(6,3): error TS2305: Module '"C:/Users/hcunwei/Library/Projects/codes/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'style'.
cilent\app\components\home.component.ts(7,3): error TS2305: Module '"C:/Users/hcunwei/Library/Projects/codes/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'animate'.
cilent\app\components\home.component.ts(8,3): error TS2305: Module '"C:/Users/hcunwei/Library/Projects/codes/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'transition'.

I have solved the problem now, the below is my solution:

1.Update to rc.2

```
"@angular/common":  "2.0.0-rc.2", 
"@angular/compiler":  "2.0.0-rc.2", 
"@angular/core":  "2.0.0-rc.2", 
"@angular/forms": "0.1.0", 
"@angular/http":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
"@angular/platform-browser":  "2.0.0-rc.2", 
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic":  "2.0.0-rc.2", 
"@angular/router":  "3.0.0-alpha.7", 
"@angular/router-deprecated":  "2.0.0-rc.2", 
"@angular/upgrade":  "2.0.0-rc.2"
```

2. Note that the *umd.js file have moved to the bundle folder, should upate the relate systemjs file config.

Comment: Are you using RC2?

Comment: @Sasxa I use "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.1" in my project, is this cause the problem?

Comment: Yes, animation was added in "2.0.0-rc.2". Update your angular...

Comment: @Sasxa thank you for you help, I will try it later.

Comment: I have updated to RC2, it's work fine now.

Comment: Glad it works. Add the solution as an answer, and accept it, so other people that have similar problem can find it more easily.